# IllegalAccessError on bigquery dataflow with apache 2.19

Tags: apache-beam-io

I have an `Apache Beam` project which process some data taken from a `BigQuery` table and then saves them back to another `BigQuery` table

This flow runs perfectly with `Apache Beam 2.18` but as soon as I upgrade to `2.19` this exception is raised

```
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1183 undefined)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1176 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:53 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112 undefined)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient.createReadSession(BigQueryStorageClient.java:237 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$StorageClientImpl.createReadSession(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1044 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryStorageSourceBase.split(BigQueryStorageSourceBase.java:139 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryStorageTableSource.split(BigQueryStorageTableSource.java:42 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory$InputProvider.getInitialInputs(BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:214 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ReadEvaluatorFactory$InputProvider.getInitialInputs(ReadEvaluatorFactory.java:89 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.RootProviderRegistry.getInitialInputs(RootProviderRegistry.java:76 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ExecutorServiceParallelExecutor.start(ExecutorServiceParallelExecutor.java:155 undefined)
    at org.apache.beamners.direct.DirectRunner.run.run(DirectRunner.java:208 undefined)
    at org.apache.beamners.direct.DirectRunner.run.run(DirectRunner.java:67 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315 undefined)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301 undefined)
    at reports.pipelines.LeadsEnricher.runPipeline(LeadsEnricher.kt:87 undefined)
    at reports.PipelineRunnerKt.main(PipelineRunner.kt:13 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.ContextUtils.CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY from class io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:384 undefined)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156 undefined)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:685 undefined)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81 undefined)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55 undefined)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156 undefined)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:766 undefined)
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.newCall(ChannelPool.java:77 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:88 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.futureCall(GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.java:65 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:86 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedUnaryCallable.futureCall(TracedUnaryCallable.java:75 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126 undefined)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87 undefined)
    ... 15 more
```

Is there something that must be done to upgrade to this version? I haven't found anything about it.

Comment: Are you using Dataflow or DirectRunner?

Comment: Are you taking this error in execution time or compilation time? The documentations says that this error is raised in execution time only if the class definition has changed (http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/annotated-java/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html).

Also, can you take a look in the release notes for the 2.19 version and tell if some of the changes can be related to your pipeline? https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12319527&version=12346582

Answer (score 1):

It's a regression of the 2.19 version [more info here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9556)